# Power Shell add SQL query results to array or table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a Power Shell script that will connect to my database and return a list of 10 ids and the associated codes. When this script is run, it list the 10 ids and then the 10 codes. I am trying to put these values into an array so I can cycle through them later in the script.

**ps1:**

```
clear

#################################################
## Connect to SQL Server Database
#################################################
[string]$serverName = 'Server'
[string]$databaseName = 'Database'
[string]$userName = 'Username'
[string]$password = 'Password'

$connectionString = 'Data Source={0};database={1};User ID={2};Password={3}' -f $serverName,$databaseName,$userName,$password

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()

#################################################
## Run SQL Query
#################################################
[string]$sqlCommand = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Table'

$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

#################################################
## Return SQL Query Results
#################################################

$dataSet.tables.id
$dataSet.tables.code

#################################################
## Close SQL Connection
#################################################

$sqlConnection.Close()
```

At the moment the the output looks like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
code1
code2
code3
code4
code5
```

I am trying to get the output to look like:

```
{
   ("1","code1"),
   ("2","code2"),
   ...
}
```

or return the data in a table format

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```sql
$dataSet.tables | Select id, code
```

Also take a look at `Select-Object`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6